# What WPF book covers GetContainerForItemOverride and related in detail?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

What WPF book covers ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride and related in detail? Additionally I would like to read about why TreeView overrides it and how IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride is related to it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what books are out there, but here is some required reading on how ItemsControls work:

- [Dr, WPF - Items Control A- Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/ItemsControlSeries/tabid/59/Default.aspx)
- [Josh Smith - Tree View and the MVVM
  Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)

I think you need to realize that Menus and TreeViews are ItemsControls, but then again so are MenuItem, and TreeViewITem. By nature a TreeView item is not only an item in a parent TreeView, but it also is a TreeView/ItemsControl itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real world example of where this override is used in relation to a TreeView control: http://blogs.msdn.com/jpricket/archive/2008/08/05/wpf-a-stretching-treeview.aspx

I hope this helps.